# how do I find the unknown coefficients of coupled equations

Tags: equation-solving

How do I find the unknown constants $x, y, z$ interms of a and b, using Mathematica.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
1&=-x+y+z \\
0&=y\frac{-4a}{b-\sqrt{b^2+8a^2}}+z\frac{-4a}{b+\sqrt{b^2+8a^2}}\\
0&=x+y+z
\end{split}
\end{equation}

```
1 = -x+y+z
0 = y(-4 a/(b-Sqrt[b^2 + 8 a^2])) + z(-4 a/(b + Sqrt[b^2+8 a^2]))
0 = x+y+z
```

where $a,b$ are real constants

Comment: see [Reduce](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) and [Solve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html) in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LinearSolve`. The matrix:

```
mat = {{-1, 1, 1},
   {0, -4 a/(b - Sqrt[b^2 + 8 a^2]), -4 a/(b + Sqrt[b^2 + 8 a^2])},
   {1, 1, 1}
   };
```

The vector:

```
v = {1, 0, 0};
```

Solving:

```
LinearSolve[mat, v]
```

yields:

```
{-(1/2), (-b + Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2])/(4 Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2]), (
 b + Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2])/(4 Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2])}
```

You could use `Solve` for the system of equations (note `==` instead of `=`).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't change much in this particular instance, but you can use `Refine` to incorporate assumptions on the parameters in your equations. Keep in mind that expressions in inequality assumptions are assumed to be real.

```
eqns = Refine[{1 == -x + y + z,
               0 == y (-4 a/(b - Sqrt[b^2 + 8 a^2])) + z (-4 a/(b + Sqrt[b^2 + 8 a^2])),
               0 == x + y + z}, 
               Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals] && Element[y, Reals]]
(* {1 == -x + y + z,
    0 == -((4 a y)/(b - Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2])) - (4 a z)/(b + Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2]),
    0 == x + y + z} *)

Solve[eqns, {x, y, z}]
    (* {{x -> -(1/2),
         y -> -((b - Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2])/(4 Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2])),
         z -> -((-b - Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2])/(4 Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2]))}} *)

Reduce[eqns, {x, y, z}]
    (* 8 a^2 + b^2 != 0 && a != 0 && x == -(1/2) && 
       y == (8 a^2 + b^2 - b Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2])/(4 (8 a^2 + b^2)) && 
       z == (8 a^2 + b^2 + b Sqrt[8 a^2 + b^2])/(4 (8 a^2 + b^2)) *)
```